# Hover Visibility

Tags: html, css, onhover

I am making a contact page for my site and I've set up this scrolling display box that is supposed to change when you hover over each icon. I've tried to make this hover effect work but I can't seem to figure it out. I used a similar effect for the dropdown menus but those work fine. I was hoping I could use one CSS effect to change all of them to "hidden" and then change them to visible separately with hover. I'm wondering, am I going to have to make a similar CSS effect for each display box?

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="icons">
            <img id="Email" title="Email" src="http://i813.photobucket.com/albums/zz56/mattboy115/Website%20Images/iconemail.png">
            <img id="Facebook" title="Facebook" src="http://i813.photobucket.com/albums/zz56/mattboy115/Website%20Images/iconfacebook.png">
            <img id="Twitter" title="Twitter" src="http://i813.photobucket.com/albums/zz56/mattboy115/Website%20Images/icontwitter.png">
            <img id="Linkedin" title="Linkedin" src="http://i813.photobucket.com/albums/zz56/mattboy115/Website%20Images/iconlinkedin.png">
            <img id="Portfolio" title="Portfolio" src="http://i813.photobucket.com/albums/zz56/mattboy115/Website%20Images/iconportfolio.png">
            <img id="iPhone" title="Phone" src="http://i813.photobucket.com/albums/zz56/mattboy115/Website%20Images/iconphone.png">
            <img id="iHome" title="Home Address" src="http://i813.photobucket.com/albums/zz56/mattboy115/Website%20Images/iconhome.png">
        </div>
        <div id="display"><p>Hover Over the Icons for Information</p>
            <div id="email"></div>
            <div id="facebook"></div>
            <div id="twitter"></div>
            <div id="linkedin"></div>
            <div id="portfolio"></div>
            <div id="phone"></div>
            <div id="home"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #main {
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    padding: 40px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    border-radius: 2px;
 }
 #icons{
    width: 30%;
    height: 1009px;
    background: #333333;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    border: black solid 5px;
 }
 #icons img {
    height: 125px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: solid black 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 08px;

 }
 #display {
    width: 52%;
    height: 350px;
    background: #333333;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    border: solid black 5px;
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 160px; 
 }
 #display div {
    width: 52%;
    height: 350px;
    background: #333333;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    border: solid black 5px;
    border-left: none;
    margin-top: -195px;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
 }
 #email:hover #Email {
    visibility: visible;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that your question is a little bit ambiguous. It seems that you want to display information when certain content is hovered over. Here is a sample code that you could use for such action, it has been simplified from your example for clarity.

**CSS**

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

/* Hides every instance that has the class hideMe within the container */
#container .hideMe {
    display: none;
}

/* Only displays the HTML that contains the class 'eMail' within the container */
#container .displayMail:hover+.eMail {
    display: block;
  /* Additional styling can be placed here for when it is visible */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <a class="displayMail">Display e-Mail</a>
    <div class="hideMe eMail">Information for e-mail should be displayed here.</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps with your issue.

Comment: I could have explained this better I think. I was using only one CSS command 

#display div { 
    visibility: hidden;
}

to hide all the divs inside the "display" div and separate commands

#Email:hover #email {
   visibility: visible;
}

to show them when hovering over the icons. I'm beginning to think that's not possible and I'm going to have to hide them all separately as well.